# Error npm install bcrypt --save. what's the solution?

Tags: node.js, npm

when i run this  npm install bcrypt --save in command line I have this below:

> `> bcrypt@2.0.0 install
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\loginApp\node_modules\bcrypt`
>
> `> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(302):
>   https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v2.0.0/bcrypt_lib-v2.0.0-node-v57-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@2.0.0 and
>   node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile
>   with node-gyp)
>
> Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable
>   parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
>
> blowfish.cc
>
> bcrypt.cc
>
> bcrypt_node.cc
>
> win_delay_load_hook.cc
>
> ..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(83): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from
>   'ssize_t' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
>   [C:\Users\User\Desktop\loginApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
>         Creating library C:\Users\User\Desktop\loginApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.lib
>   and object
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\loginApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.exp
>   Generating code    Finished generating code    bcrypt_lib.vcxproj ->
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\loginApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.node
>   bcrypt_lib.vcxproj ->
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\loginApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.pdb
>   (Full PDB)    Copying
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\loginApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release/bcrypt_lib.node
>   to
>   C:/Users/User/Desktop/loginApp/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding\bcrypt_lib.node
>
> ```
>          1 file(s) copied.
> ```
>
> npm WARN loginapp@1.0.0 No description
>
> npm WARN loginapp@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> - bcrypt@2.0.0
>
> updated 1 package in 23.239s

I installed  npm install -g node-gyp

and npm install --global --production windows-build-tools successfully

because i couldnt install bcrypt module before.

Now i can install bcrypt module but i have this error.

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using?

Comment: node v8.9.4 and  npm v5.6.0

Comment: I tried this npm install bcrypt@1.0.3 --save and installed successfully

the Error is when i try to install bcrypt@2.0.0